# JDialog and JFrame and new instance

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have 2 classes - a JFrame with a button, and a JDialog (a pop up) with few textfields on it. Now, when I click the button in JFrame a JDialog shows up:

```
/*** someClass class ****/  
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            jd = new jDialog();
            jd.setModal(true);
            jd.setVisible(true);    
        }
    });
public void doStuff(String one....String five){
   ... ..
  }
```

Now a jDialog pops up and i need to fill up some textfields inside it and click another button to confirm.

```
/*** jDialog class ***/   
JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            one = 1_tf.getText();
            two = 2_tf.getText();
            three = 3_tf.getText();
            four = 4_tf.getText();
            five = 5_tf.getText();

            doAnything(one,two,three,four,five);

            1_tf.setText("");
            2_tf.setText("");
            3_tf.setText("");
            4_tf.setText("");
            5_tf.setText("");                           
        }
    });

public void doAnything(String one,String two,String three,String four,String five){

 someClass sc = new someClass();
 sc.doStuff(one,two,three,four,five);        
}
```

The textfield's values will be passed to doAnything() method, inside doAnything() is an instance of someClass class to access sc.doStuff() method and pass the values.

The problem now is that, Whenever I click confirm on jDialog class a new JFrame appears so there are 2 JFrames which is not what I want.. It's like whenever I do something on jdialog it creates a new JFrame instead of over lapping the original JFrame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doAnything() don't recreate the someClass (it's better to read java naming convention -classes should start from capital letter) instances.

Define class field for the someClass  instance? create it just once (if it's null) and reuse it.

Comment: declare it outside the doAnything()?

Comment: yes. but you can initialize it in the doAnything() on first call

Comment: It's working now.. I have one more question though. On the screen, it resets  the JFrame somehow for ex. I picked Item 4 on jComboBox then I click  the button that calls jDialog, the jComoBox resets to Item 0 and then when I close the jDialog the jComboBox comes back to Item 4

Comment: it works then accept the answer as correct. As for the second question post another one with code from te doAnything(). It's hard to tell without cde the reason

Comment: That's the only code for the doAnything() it temporarily resets like when you first open your JFrame without changing any JcomboBox items.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because in the `someClass` constructor you create an show a JFrame. To avoid this problem, make a `static` reference to the `doStuff()` method.

Declare it as:

```
public static doStuff(one, two, three, four, five) {
    ...
}
```

and use it as:

```
someClass.doStuff(one, two, three, four, five);
```

Now, when you use the method, you don't have to create an object of `someClass` class, and then you don't have to call the constructor method.

Comment: Is there an alternative for static references? I'm really trying to avoid using static :|

Comment: Yes, take an instance of `someClass` in your `jDialog class` constructor. Doeing so, you already have the `someClass` instance and you don't have to create another one in the `doAnything()` method. So, create a `someClass` (`JFrame`), then create a `jDialog class` (`JDialog`) passing the `someClass` instance into the `jDialog class`. Then use the `someClass` instance into the `jDialog class` (in the `doAnything()` method).